# Importing Maven Projects in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I am an Eclipse user who is trying out IntelliJ IDEA. When importing a maven project, in the wizard, I am asked to "Select profile". What aspects of the project is decided on this selection?

Comment: The easiest way to open a maven project is to use File -> Open... and open root pom.xml of your project.

Answer (score 3):

It lets you activate different profiles that are found in your pom.xml. The docs shown above give good information but not really how you would use a profile. For example, you may have a ''dev' profile for building in your dev environment or a ''production' profile for building when you are ready to deploy.  Maven allows you to use a profile by using its 'P' flag after your build command, followed by the actual profile. Eg.

`mvn clean install -Pdev`

Hope this helps!

Comment: But why do I have to select profiles when importing to idea, if I will use a command like above to run a certain profile. I can do it even without idea, from the command line.

Comment: It just chooses which ones are activated when you import the project. Maven builds can be run using the "maven goals" feature in IntelliJ, so whatever ones you do not tick when you import the project are not going to be available when you try and run a maven goal in intelliJ. Realistically, you are probably better off ticking them all just in case you need them.

Answer (score 1):

I usually don't select any profiles when I import a maven project for the first time.

Once you have imported it, you can later come back and tick any profiles you want to enable / disable prior to executing a build step (like `clean install`).

This seems the most straight forward approach to me.

Answer (score 0):

It affects the way projects are imported

See doc : [profiles](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/activating-and-deactivating-maven-profiles.html?search=profile)